# Argument of type 'Session | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Session'

Tags: express, typescript-typings, express-session

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```sh
npm install express express-cookies @types/cookie-session @types/express-session
```

```js
import express from express();
import cookieSession from 'cookie-session';


const app = express();

app.use(cookieSession({
    name: 'session',
    keys: [
        process.env.SESSION_KEY as string
    ]
}));

const router = express.Router();

const changeSession = (session = express.Session) => {
    session.foo = 'bar'
}

router.get((req, res) => {
    changeSession(req.session)
});
```

On `changeSession(req.session)` I get the error:

```
Argument of type 'Session | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Session'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type  'Session'
```

Same happens when I use `app.get` instead of `router.get`

Not sure why express-cookies isn't registering the session object to the request properly.

Here's a link to @types/cookie-session: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/cookie-session/index.d.ts which provides typings for `express-cookies`

Any help?

Comment: Normally, express by itself, if I tried to refer to `req.session` I would get undefined from that. By default, a request object does not have a session property, just like normally a request object does not have a body property. It is only the fact that we add in this `cookieSession` middleware that the request object will get a session property attached to it. Thats how the session property comes into existence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The express-cookies typings specify that `req.session` can be `undefined`. As I understand, `req.session` will be defined only if you register the `cookieSession` middleware with express. So, if for any reason you won't register this middleware (e.g., delete the code which registers it by mistake), `req.session` will be undefined.

Because there is a possibility that the session middleware may not be registered, type-wise it is correct to expect that `req.session` may be `undefined`.

So, using TS you would need to check if `req.session` is defined before working with it:

```
if (req.session) {
    changeSession(req.session)
}
```

Or throw an error explicitly if the session is mandatory for a route:

```
if (!req.session) {
    throw new Error('Session is missing.');
}

changeSession(req.session)
```

Or as last resort, use the exclamation mark to tell TS that `req.session` is actually defined:

```
changeSession(req.session!)
```

But this won't be type-safe.

Comment: Can you point me to the line in express-cookies typings that specify that `req.session` can be undefined?

Comment: This line: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/3c19dc1b87942cc3ccff9afc4f7d0b368c9113c4/types/cookie-session/index.d.ts#L106
In the beginning of the file they use declaration merging to merge original Express.Request interface with CookieSessionRequest.

Answer (score 0):

The error is quite explicit, `express.Session` may be `undefined` and the `changeSession` function is declared to expect a parameter of type `Session` (not `Session | undefined`).

If you are sure your `express.Session` object won't be `undefined`, you can assign the default parameter value like so

```
const changeSession = (session = express.Session!) => {
    session.foo = 'bar'
}
```

Notice the exclamation mark (*!*) after the value. It forces the compiler to forget about `undefined` values.
This is quite tricky and, of course, you could end having runtime exceptions if this `express.Session` is `undefined`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Exactly, non null assertions are usually a bad idea. The reason I'm confused why it's expecting `Session | Undefined` is because when I use `express-session` it doesn't give me this error. So why is it happening here?